# Реализация механизма пользовательских событих на C++

Tags: c++, события

Для работы с событиями ввода-вывода можно использовать такие встроенные в ОС механизмы, как IOCP/epoll/kqueue. Но что, если надо реализовать нечто подобное для пользовательских событий? Например, где-то в параллельном потоке произошла вставка в общий буфер, и теперь мы знаем, что оттуда можно взять новые данные, а не опрашиваем этот буфер под мьютексом с определённой периодичностью.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это делается на С++?

Comment: Ммм, только кастомное решение.

Comment: Ну boost.signal например

Comment: Для приведенного вами примера хорошо подходит std::condition_variable